# Filter cards in Bootstrap 4 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to create a page that is populated by many cards, using bootstrap 4's new card component.

I want to create a search bar, that when searched, filters out cards whose titles don't match the search query.

Here is a plunker of what I have in mind. [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/2oZIRIbXoXJauiVtEzLq/)

I would like the cards to get something like a `display: none`, or `opacity:0` if they don't match.

I currently am attempting to write a function that `onChange` of the search bar does this. I'll post if I can get it figured out.

I've tried to use the built in snippet feature as well.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-block">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-block card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
        <footer>
          <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card card-block text-xs-right">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to filter by? Title? Text?

Comment: Title for now, sorry, I thought I put that in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could do it using jQuery's [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('.searchbox-input').change( function () {
    $('.card').show();
    var filter = $(this).val(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
    $('.container').find(".card-title:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().css('display','none');
});
```

Currently this is set up to happen on change of the search input, you would probably want set up a submit button and have it fire on submit instead.

## [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/mqPlhqQsg7)

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for, I've not used the contains selector before. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong jQuery docs page before, it's actually the `contains selector`. Updated now. Happy to help!

Comment: This code does not have a way to reset the filter so that all the cards are displayed, also, when the cards are filtered, the header is not shown.

Comment: @APAD1 This looks really useful, how would you reset them back to normal if you emptied the search string?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few more modern options that are Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 5 friendly...

**Bootstrap 5 (using JavaScript)**

```
var buttonUp = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector(".searchbox-input");
    const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    let filter = input.value
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body");
        if (title.innerText.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].classList.remove("d-none")
        } else {
            cards[i].classList.add("d-none")
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/asG3K2Opbi)

**Bootstrap 4 (using jQuery)**

```
// this overrides `contains` to make it case insenstive
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

var buttonUp = () => {
    $('.card').removeClass('d-none');
    var filter = $(this).val(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
    $('.card-deck').find('.card .card-body h4:not(:contains("'+filter+'"))').parent().parent().addClass('d-none');
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/go/KvTSAFv2bv)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchbox-input').on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchForm').keyup(function(){
        search_text($(this).val());
    });

    function search_text(value){
        $('#search_section .card').each(function(){
            var found = 'false';
            $(this).each(function(){
                if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                {
                    found = 'true';
                }
            });
            if(found == 'true'){
                $(this).show()
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })
    }
});
```